# Share /etc/hosts between root machine and containers

Tags: routing, openvz, hosts-file

I have a Centos machine with OpenVZ containers. For each container I have an alias in `/etc/hosts`. I would like to be able to share the `/etc/hosts` between the root and the containers. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by sharing? Do you want all containers to have the same /etc/hosts? It's not a good idea because it should contain a hostname. But if you want to be able to view it's contents inside a container then you can do use `mount --bind` from a host:

```
mount --bind /etc/hosts ${VE_ROOT}/root/shared_etc_host
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a configuration deployment mechanism like Chef, Ansible or Puppet to deploy consitent `/etc/hosts` file in your env.